# Babel doesn't transpile subfolders

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler, babel-cli

My folder structure:

```
package.json
src
├── backend
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── myRoute.js
├── index.js
├── .babelrc
```

The command i run from `package.json`: `"build:server": "babel src/backend/ -d dist"`

The resulting `dist` folder structure:

```
dist
├── src
│   ├── backend
    │   ├── index.js
```

How can i get it to transpile all subfolders within `backend` as well? I tried `babel src/backend/** -d dist` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Looks like `index.js` contains everything. Do you wanna check the source?

Comment: What do you mean it contains everything? I am importing `myRoute.js` in `index.js`. After babel transpiles it and i try to run the `index.js` in `dist` with `node`, I get an error saying `./routes/myRoute.js` cannot be found.

Comment: What if you move `.babelrc` out of `src` and into the root-level? Then change your command to `babel src -d dist`

Comment: @BenLorantfy The problem with that is that i already have a root-level `.babelrc` which handles the frontend transpilation

Answer (score 1):

You should move your `.babelrc` file to the root of your directory